# When X, better Y than Z

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this construction correct? It sounds good but slightly ungrammatical to me. However, I'm not a native English speaker so I'm not very sure.

Example:

> When anxious, better drunk than full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a complete sentence, as it lacks a verb. It is correct if one is willing to accept it as a shortening of something like.

> When (you are) anxious, (it is) better (that you are) drunk than full.

It works better as a slogan than as a sentence in a piece of prose.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense, but it is best used colloquially(with friends or informally) not formally. 
Grammatically, it lacks the verbal element that is necessary in any any sentence structure (Subject - Verb - Object). Though drunk is a past tense of the verb drink, in this contact it is an adjective.

So basically, it makes sense. But inappropriate in formal contexts.